# Correlating list properties in phing

Tags: php, foreach, properties, phing

I have an automated deployment system working using Phing.  We are adding a second server and I need to modify the deployment target in order to handle this. My issue is that the paths to deploy to between the two servers are not the same, so I'm not sure how to associate the current deploy server with the path I need to deploy to.

In my main `phing.xml` file, I set up properties:

```
<property name="deploy.servers.production"    value="server1.com,server2.com" />
<property name="deploy.path.production"       value="/path/on/server1,/path/on/server2" />
```

During the build, I just have a `foreach` element that iterates over the different servers and calls an upload task setting them as a property:

```
<foreach list="${deploy.servers.production}" param="deploy.server" target="deploy.deliver" />
```

The problem I have is that I can't find [a way to associate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12350718/697370) the *path* that I need to deliver to with the *server* that I'm currently deploying to. What I would like to avoid is having to have separate properties for each server, something like this:

```
<property name="deploy.servers.production1"    value="server1.com" />
<property name="deploy.servers.production2"    value="server2.com" />
<property name="deploy.path.production1"       value="/path/on/server1" />
<property name="deploy.path.production2"       value="/path/on/server2" />
```

Is there a way to have two separate list properties in phing that correlate with one another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up having to write two custom phing tasks for this. One of them was basically just an adding of feature to the [`foreach`](https://github.com/phingofficial/phing/blob/master/classes/phing/tasks/system/ForeachTask.php) task, which I added as a gist on github [here](https://gist.github.com/jeffsrepoaccount/d7613eb3b97c977a483562abef38bf40).  The other one is a much simpler task that is used to retrieve an item in a delimited list property by index, which I also added as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/jeffsrepoaccount/03525d2b2ff3432ee31643528c9d8ef9).  Importing these tasks works like this:

```
<includepath    classpath="${base.dir}${ds}Tasks${ds}" />
<taskdef name="foreachkey"      classname="ForeachKeyTask" />
<taskdef name="listitembykey"   classname="ListItemByKeyTask" />

<property name="deploy.targets.production"          value="server1,server2,server3" />
<property name="deploy.users.production"            value="user1,user2,user3" />
<property name="deploy.privateKeys.production"      value=".ssh/key1_rsa,.ssh/key2_rsa,.ssh/key3_rsa" />
<property name="deploy.publicKeys.production"       value=".ssh/key1_rsa.pub,.ssh/key2_rsa.pub,.ssh/key3_rsa.pub" />
<property name="deploy.paths.production"            value="/path/on/server1,/path/on/server2,/path/on/server3" />
```

The list of servers is iterated over similarly to using the `<foreach>` task, with the minor addition of adding a property name to keep track of the current index:

```
<foreachkey list="deploy.targets" key="currentIndex" param="deploy.server" target="install" />
```

The callee then has two properties that it can then access, `deploy.server` to get the current value in the list of target servers, and `currentIndex` that references the current index in the list.  Using this, I can now get the other associated values:

```
<-- The properties above get aliased to these properties when the target environment is selected -->
<listitembykey key="currentIndex" property="deploy.users" returnval="user" />
<listitembykey key="currentIndex" property="deploy.privateKeys" returnval="privateKey" />
<listitembykey key="currentIndex" property="deploy.publicKeys" returnval="publicKey" />
<listitembykey key="currentIndex" property="deploy.paths" returnval="path" />

<!-- Properties now available that hold the current credential information related to 
     the current deployment target:
        user, privateKey, publicKey, passphrase, path -->

<!-- And they can be used to execute SSH commands... -->

<netssh username="${user}"
    pubkeyfile="${publicKey}"
    privkeyfile="${privateKey}"
    host="${deploy.server}"
    sshlib="${deploy.sshlib}"
    command="mkdir -p ${path}${ds}${deploy.releasedir}${ds}${deploy.ts}" />
```

The downside to this approach is that you have to keep the associated data in the same indices.  Even if the username (or keys, or paths) between server1 and server2 is the same, you still have to list it twice (in my case they are different).